# Script to ping all machines in the network, to find the machines that are on?

Tags: windows, networking, scripting, ping

I am looking for a simple script (that can be executed in windows platform)  to ping all machines, and to write the IP of "On" machines (machines that'll reply) to a text file.

Answer (score 6):

nmap -sP

Performs a ping scan (host discovery), then print out the available hosts that responded to the scan. No further testing (such as port scanning or OS detection) is performed.

Comment: Download at http://nmap.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fping](http://fping.sourceforge.net/), for example:

```
/usr/sbin/fping -g 192.168.1.0/24 -a
```

Will print all IPs answering to ping on the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following program [Netscan](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/), I think this will do what you want..